# Rational and Irrational Angles

Tags: geometry

What are rational and irrational angles? Are they just angles, the radian measure of which is respectively rational or irrational?

They came up in conversation, and I tried researching them, but didn't find any good resources. Any brief explanation/pointer to a useful resource would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rational angles are rational multiples of $\pi$ radians, which also means a rational fraction of a circle.

Comment: In other words, a rational number of degrees!